# App engine datastore, query sorted by fk attribute

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on the datastore of google app engine, and I'm developing an app for manage events.
I have 2 entity:

```
- user
- event
    - attribute eventDate
```

A user can follow one or more event, so I create the link table

```
- UserEvent
    -User key
    -Event key
```

**My problem is that I would like to have a list of the events followed by the user, ordered by eventDate.**

How can I do?

I found 3 solution, but I don't like anyone...

1. Query on all the event ordered, and then iterate and choose only the
   one with has one occurency on UserEvent *(I don't like because
   probably I will have thousand of event, but a user follow only
   few..)*
2. Query on all the user event (filtered by userKey) and put the result
   in an ordered list *(I don't like because I have to load all Event at
   once, without pagination)*
3. Add in table UserEvent the attribute eventDate *(I don't like because
   if an event has 3000 followers I have to do 3000 update...)*

Thank you
Alessandro

Comment: Alternatively if you always query events for 1 given user, you can consider storing a ListProperty of Events in the User entity.

Comment: mmm, that's right, I query for single user. but if I put all followed events in user, the user entity could became too big?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like such denormalization, consider using CloudSQL.

Comment: I'm not sure, I like denormalization, but I work always with relational db... I'm in the starting phase of creating the app, so I can change also the structure of the db. What do you think about my solutions? there will be something better?

Comment: between relational o non relational? I don't know, I always use relational, but I'm curious about non relational (and if all the big that have tons of data use non relational, I think that are good...). By the way, I'm developing on app engine, so I think that there isn't choise... On the solution better means the one is less expansive in quering, and more solid...

Answer (score 0):

If you always query events for a given user, you can consider storing a ListProperty of Events in the User entity.

```
- user
    - attribute eventList []key
```

You will be limited by the maximum size of an entity (currently 1MB) and if the list is indexed your're limited to 5000 entries.

Comment: 5000 entity are a lot... If my app will have some user that follow 5000 events I will very happy :-) I'll think about it... thanks